# With Pywinauto, how do I know what the name of the started application is?

Tags: python, pywinauto

I'm trying to play around with Pywinauto and I have a basic program that will simply start a program, and click on it, looks like so:

```
from pywinauto import application
app = application.Application()

app.Start_("//PathToGChrome/Google Chrome.exe")

# Google Chrome Starts

app.Google_Chrome.ClickInput(coords=(0,0))

# Returns error:

Could not find 'Google_Chrome` in `dict_keys([])`
```

But if I did like

```
app.Start_('Notepad.exe')

# Notepad Starts

app.Notepad.ClickInput(coords=(0,0))

# Foregrounds notepad and clicks in the top left
```

How come Google Chrome could not be found? Is it because there is a space in the name? How do I know what the proper name is for Google Chrome??

Comment: As far as I know Google Chrome is named `chrome.exe`. "Google Chrome" should be a shortcut.

Comment: right click "//PathToGChrome/Google Chrome.exe" and go to Properties->Details, you should see what the actual exe file is. Should be something like: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

Comment: Chrome GUI is not native. So you are not able to automate it in a nice way using pywinauto now. You can use UI Automation API directly (UIAutomationCore.dll with custom COM interface through `comtypes` package) or wait for nice wrappers in future pywinauto releases.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the internal search of pywinauto for a window title fails because the Chrome's window process ID is different from PID of the Chrome's launcher. The simplest way to you would be just use Swapy helper application (https://code.google.com/p/swapy/) It's a bit outdated but still works and helps you to generate a working code. At least for the beginning. 
Run Swapy after launching Chrome and find the application title in the list. Right click on the item and choose an action to perform. This is example of the code:

```
import pywinauto

pwa_app = pywinauto.application.Application()
w_handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title=u'New Tab - Google Chrome', class_name='Chrome_WidgetWin_1')[0]
window = pwa_app.window_(handle=w_handle)
window.ClickInput()
```